# What is the error in creating new rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`dilip@linuxmint~ rails new treebook`

```
/home/dilip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext  /kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)
from /home/dilip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/lib/rails_generator.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/dilip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
from /home/dilip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/bin/rails:16:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone please help me out with this error??

Comment: You may need to provide more detail regarding your problem.

Comment: How did you install rails?

Comment: Have you done `gem install rails`?

Comment: @tolgap i installed it by  "rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448"

Comment: @Lt_Shade more details like?

Comment: @DmitryPolushkin i installed rubygems

Comment: As @tolgap mentioned "How did you install rails?"

Comment: Thanks @DmitryPolushkin i did "gem install rails" and it works. My new project i.e treebook is created.. thanks all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have done

```
    gem install rails
```

Also, make sure that you have all the proper permissions to your gems (i.e. they don't belong to root)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Rails is installed then use command

> bundle install